# How to get query plan for a running process in mysql

Tags: mysql

I can see currently running processes using `show processlist;`. It gives me partial text of the query which is running.
I want to know how can I see the query plan for this process using the Id.

"Explain" command of mysql accepts table name or a full query, but it doesn't accept a running query's id.

Comment: you can't. what else can we say

Comment: We can now say "you can", [see answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37672341/2738164)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL 5.7 has new feature to check execution plan for running queries using EXPLAIN FOR CONNECTION.

**[You can visit this article for more details.](http://www.dbrnd.com/2016/02/mysql-5-7-introduced-explain-for-connection-to-check-the-execution-plan-of-running-connections/)**

```
EXPLAIN [options] FOR CONNECTION connection_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write function something like this.

```
select info into @query from information_schema.processlist where id=3206933;
SET @stmt = CONCAT('explain ', @query);
use `database`
PREPARE stmt FROM @stmt;
EXECUTE stmt;
```